# How can i show a jquery menu which opens from right to left side?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to show a menu on clicking on a link. The menu should appear from right to left with show function.
I have already tried
    $('.amenu').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, "fast");
But it comes sliding. I want the same effect as
    $('.amenu').show("fast");
but menu originating from top right corner.

Comment: You want something like a 'grow' animation? Or just a simple slide?

Comment: I was looking for a grow animation . Like menu originates from top right corner and forms a box shaped menu.

Comment: Check my answer, It's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this fiddle for you which you can use in any way. The idea is that the menu is put in position with this css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

If you play around you can make it stick anywhere.
The animation is also done with CSS using this class and you can leave only width if you want a slide animation:

```
.animate {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s; 
  -o-transition: width 1s, height 1s; 
}
```

And a simple jQuery to toggle the class.

https://jsfiddle.net/mtucpL3v/

Further reading: [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)